# What is the maximum likelihood estimator of a distribution with PDF, $f(x) = x/8$ for $x$ in $[0,\theta]$?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, distributions, version-9

If I input:

```
data = RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, 4}], 10];
{EstimatedDistribution[data, ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, θ}],
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"], data}
```

Mathematica returns:

```
{ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/
  8, {\[FormalX], 0, 4.99291}], {3.8921, 2.93817, 2.07761, 1.12473, 
  3.96292, 1.20091, 2.86696, 1.52381, 2.43073, 3.13515}}
```

I think the mle for a sample from this distribution is the maximum of the sample. What is Mathematica computing here?  In other words,  why is Mathematica returning 4.99291?

From [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191673/what-is-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-a-distribution-with-pdf-fx-x-8#comment499117_191674):

> I just now restarted Mathematica and I am getting the same bad results. I am using version 9.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.  On the data shown, which lack significant digits, I get `ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/8, {\[FormalX], 0, 3.96292}]`.

Comment: In v11.3 `Options[EstimatedDistribution, ParameterEstimator]` evaluates to 

`{ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"}`, If also the case for your version, it is unnecessary to specify that option. Also, for 200 trials, `And @@ Table[
  data = RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, 4}], 10]; 
  EstimatedDistribution[data, 
     ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, \[Theta]}]][[-1, -1]] == 
   Max@data, {200}]` evaluated to `True`. Problem must be version specific.

Comment: I think the question is confused. If the pdf is $f = x/8$, then the domain of support must be $(0,4)$ in order for the pdf to be well-defined. There is NO unknown parameter to this distribution. What do you propose to find the MLE of? There is nothing to estimate.

Comment: @wolfies.  Yes thank you.  You are right.  The question is bad.  I am trying to estimate $\theta$ in a random sample with pdf $2x/\theta^2$ with $0<x<\theta$.  The mle is the max of the sample.  Mathematica takes : dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
  2 x/\[Theta]^2, {x, 0, \[Theta]}]; EstimatedDistribution[{1, 2, 3, 
  4, 5}, dist]  and returns  ProbabilityDistribution[0.0987654 \[FormalX], {\[FormalX], 0, 4.5}] with a note saying this might not be a max.

Comment: The 0.987654 is, of course, 2/4.5^2.  I suspect that what you'd like *Mathematica* to give is a symbolic answer:  `Max[data]`.  But I don't know if that's possible.  Even if one doesn't know that the answer is `Max[data]`, one does know that `theta >= Max[data]` so the following will work:  `FindMaximum[{LogLikelihood[dist, data], Theta >= Max[data]}, Theta]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log-likelihood of the OP's (non-normalized) distribution is piecewise constant, so any value for `θ` that occurs in a certain interval is "correct," at least from the point of view of maximizing the expression returned by `LogLikelihood[]`.  As [@wolfies points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191673/what-is-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-of-a-distribution-with-pdf-fx-x-8#comment499132_191673), the distribution is not valid, so while *Mathematica* is willing to compute with it, it's unclear what the meaning of the result is from a probability/statistics point of view.

While V11.3 and V9 return different answers, both are equally correct.  One might quibble that in V11.3, `EstimatedDistribution` has been reprogrammed to return the boundary value `3.96292` in the piecewise log-likelihood function, which is technically not in the open interval over which the function attains its maximum.  In V9, my guess is that the initial estimate for `θ` is greater than `3.96292`, where the Jacobian is zero and the search stops.

```
data = {3.8921`, 2.93817`, 2.07761`, 1.12473`, 3.96292`, 1.20091`, 
   2.86696`, 1.52381`, 2.43073`, 3.13515`};
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/8, {\[FormalX], 0, θ}];

LogLikelihood[dist, data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Remark.  Perhaps one should be using the normalized distribution:

```
ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/8, {\[FormalX], 0, θ}, Method -> "Normalize"]
```

This does depend on a parameter `θ`, which could be estimated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` has only 10 samples of random values. This can result in discrepancy between the the PDF and estimation.

You will have almost 4 for 1000 samples:

```
data = 
 RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, 4}], 1000];
{EstimatedDistribution[data, ProbabilityDistribution[x/8, {x, 0, θ}], 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]}
(* {ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/
  8, {\[FormalX], 0, 3.99886}]} *)
```

Comment: I copied your code above and Mathematica returned:  {ProbabilityDistribution[\[FormalX]/8, {\[FormalX], 0, 5.02721}]}   I ran it several times and it was always around 5.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer  You all really ought to make your results reproducible.  Look up `SeedRandom[]`.  Geoffrey, which version are you using?  Have you tried restarting *Mathematica*?

Comment: @ MichealE2.   I just now restarted Mathematica and I am getting the same bad results.  I am using version 9.